# Unable to use variable in DATEADD(@pinterval, @pinterval, @DayPlus)

Tags: t-sql, variables, dynamic, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @pinterval INT = 1, @DayPlus DATETIME = '2016-07-01', @datepart VARCHAR(20) = 'MONTH'
SET @DayPlus = DATEADD(@datepart, @pinterval, @DayPlus)
SELECT @DayPlus
```

Do we have any alternative to accomplish task ? I have to do it in loop so I can't define it every time based on interval value. Only date part is not acceptable as variable because if I use as

```
DATEADD(MONTH, @pinterval, @DayPlus)
```

then it's working fine. Not sure but I can understand the issue but I am seeking for the quick solution. I have visited the web but didn't get exact solution.

Comment: Yes, the first argument to `DATEADD` needs to be the *name* of a date component. Not a *string* (literal or variable) that *contains* the name of a date component.

Comment: That means, it's not possible in anyways ?

Comment: Yes it is ... use a dynamic query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to substitute a variable for the first argument to [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx)<sup>1</sup>, since what is wanted here is a *name*, not a *string*.

About the best you can do is a `CASE` expression:

```
SET @DayPlus =
CASE @datepart
    WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, @pinterval, @DayPlus)
    WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @pinterval, @DayPlus)
    WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY, @pinterval, @DayPlus)
    --TODO - add all parts you might wish to use
END
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This is even stated in the documentation:

> User-defined variable equivalents are not valid.

Comment: Thank you for the response, if this is only the way then I have to repeat this for more than 10times if I am working with that much date parts ??

Comment: @Suraz probably not... Read about `CROSS APPLY(SELECT ...) AS t`. This allows you to place the calculation once and use its result as a named *derived column*

Comment: @Shnugo it sounds good, can you please help me by placing the complete code as an answer. Please !!

Answer (score 2):

> if this is only the way then I have to repeat this for more than 10times

No, use `CROSS APPLY`

> @Shnugo it sounds good, can you please help me by placing the complete code as an answer. Please !!

About `CROSS APPLY`: generate something like a variable dynamically

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT, SomeDate DATE);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(1,{d'2017-01-01'}),(2,{d'2017-02-02'})
GO
DECLARE @Intervall VARCHAR(100)='DAY';
DECLARE @Count INT=1

SELECT dbo.Test.*
      ,t.AddedDate
FROM dbo.Test
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE @Intervall WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATEADD(MONTH,@Count,SomeDate)
                                   WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY,@Count,SomeDate)
                                   ELSE SomeDate END AS AddedDate) AS t;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
```

Comment: Thank you sir +1 for your effort and distinct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @pinterval INT = 1, 
  @DayPlus DATETIME = '2016-07-01', 
  @datepart NVARCHAR(20) = 'MONTH'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SET @DayPlus = DATEADD('+@datepart+', @pinterval, @DayPlus)',
       @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@DayPlus DATETIME OUTPUT, @pinterval INT'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @pinterval = @pinterval, @DayPlus = @DayPlus OUTPUT

SELECT @DayPlus
```

[sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) is used for 2 reasons:

1. to minimize SQL injections risk, it will not eliminate it because of @datepart
2. it will make sure your dynamic query's plan is going to be cached - which might be beneficial with simple queries (where query time vs compilation time matters)

Comment: `@DayPlus = @DayPlus OUTPUT` if you actually want to get the result back.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks! Missed it.